# Software for creating fonts

Tags: typography, software-recommendation

What consumer-usable tools exist for font creation?

Ideally I'd like an OSS solution, but inexpensive commercial offerings are viable, too.

Comment: See this previous question: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/how-do-you-make-a-font-in-illustrator

Comment: +1 for this, just had the desire to mess around with making fonts yesterday!

Answer (score 1):

One popular option is [Font Creator](http://www.high-logic.com/fontcreator.html). Very huge options, full control, overall very nice piece of software in my opinion.

You could also try the [yourfonts.com](http://www.yourfonts.com/) which allows you to input handwriting letters to your own font with few steps. (In a more easy way than with Font Creator)

I think these free options available might be good enough for you or anyone creating own fonts.

Comment: Font Creator gets my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Fontself](https://www.fontself.com) could be interesting.

It is not really expensive ($49) and really consumer-usable because it makes it easy to create your font right from Adobe Illustrator without deep knowledge about typography.