# I want to make font, I have digitized the characters, how to proceed next?

Tags: typography, typefaces, font-design

Basically I want to learn how to use the kerning, spacing, ligatures
to make it more legible. If any one knows any tutorials or guide available online please let me know.

thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you make a font in illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/how-do-you-make-a-font-in-illustrator)

Comment: What software are you using? FontLab? Fontographer? Glyph?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! As Scott says, we need to know what software you are using. What you have created the characters in? Scott hints at some SW that will help you achieve what you want.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend creating fonts in Illustrator. Both Illustrator and whichever pro Font-creation app you choose will require you learn the pen tool to draw your glyphs.  Starting in a separate program might seem attractive to those familiar with Adobe's interface, but you'd just be adding addition steps to the process.  The only reason I can see to start in AI is if you want to apply effects and textures that you couldn’t do in an app like FontLab.

Comment: @Moscarda you can export stuff form illustrator i one go. But more prominently you cab use illustrators effect stack to make the fonts procedural

Comment: I know you can export from one to the other, I was merely recommending avoiding this if possible because it adds steps to an already lengthy process.  If you can draw/trace with the pen tool in one application, you can do it in the rest.

Answer (score 2):

If you're a beginner, I actually DO recommend you start out with something simpler and cheaper. Fontlab and Glyphs are awesome programs, but they're also expensive and have loads and loads of features you might not need at the moment.

Some lower-budget but competent font editors:

- [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/)- more than competent, free, open source, multiplatform. Can be overwhelming and has an ugly interface, but there's plenty of documentation online.
- [Glyphs Mini](https://glyphsapp.com/glyphs-mini) - Mac only. Glyphs younger and cheaper brother.
- [Typetool](http://old.fontlab.com/font-editor/typetool/)- Mac/Win. Fontlab's younger and cheaper brother
- [FontCreator](http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html) - Windows only, but very complete, with good support.
- [Type 3.2](http://www.cr8software.net/type.html) - Very simple, but has the basics. Mac/Win. Free version available

All these should more than cover a beginner's need. If you're serious about designing typefaces, you can upgrade to a more advanced tool.

Comment: Glyphs mini is a great piece of software. Very easy to use and very reasonably priced. You can get a discounted upgrade to Glyphs too so upgrading when you need the extra features won't cost you a bomb.

Answer (score 1):

You would need specific software to make an actually usable and quality font. I don't think that anyone that's serious about fonts uses anything else than [FontLab](http://www.fontlab.com) or [Glyphs](http://www.glyphsapp.com) on OSX.

And to get help creating a really good font I'd suggest joining a great forum like [Typophile](http://www.typophile.com). There are many experts and world renown typographers there that give practical advice and help to others. They'll give you constructive critique of your work and help you get the most out of it.

Answer (score 1):

With Typophile offline, and all signs point to that being permanent, I would recommend visiting "[Phinney on Fonts](http://www.thomasphinney.com/)".  That is Thomas Phinney, type designer and enthusiast and president of FontLab.  His site features some great tutorials, links to other important sites, lists of must-have books on the subject, and more.  He is also a member [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/57612/thomas-phinney) at the Graphic Design StackExchange.  You should also check out the [FontLab Videos YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/fontlabvideos), for his free video tutorials (and other authors) on learning the skills you are talking about in FontLab.

Other resources include the official [FontLab forums](http://forum.fontlab.com/): everyone there is super friendly and knowledgeable—the Manuals and Tutorials on the [FontLab website](http://old.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontlab-studio/fontlab-studio-tutorials/), and paid courses with sites like Lynda, Udemy and the like.

I would not recommend using anything but FontLab Studio or Glyphs—Fontographer does not support opentype features or kerning tables.  I haven't personally tried Glyphs, but I hear good things.  FontLab has been the industry standard since 1993 in one form or another (it's changed hands between 3 or 4 companies since its inception).

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above—you can create your original art in another application, such as Illustrator, then import. I've used FontLab Studio to create type this way, and is a good way to gain familiarity with type design. Once you become more comfortable with FontLab, though, it probably will be better to start there first.

As to the costs, well, it depends. $600 for FontLab may be a bit steep, but consider the time/use you will expend. Having a well-functioning tool may be work the cost of entry, if you plan to be doing more type design work.