# What font is used in Kulu's logo?

Tags: font-identification

Kulu is a company that makes rolling papers. I was looking for a high res image of their logo and when I realized I couldn't find one I was gearing up to re-create it but became interested in what the type they used was. I'm also interested in any similar fonts as I suspect this may be custom.

I tried using identifont but because there are only 3 letters in the brand name it wasn't conclusive. The same goes for Whatthefont, as the image is so lo-res it's not picking up the letterforms. I tried Serif search too, but again a lack of letters doesnt lend to making this search easy.

[image: Kulu logo]

Comment: Create your own font. As @Alan Gilbertson said in [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/3255/42511) : To create a font, you need a font editing program. [FontCreator](http://www.high-logic.com/fontcreator.html) is quite popular and inexpensive. [FontForge](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/typetool/) is an open source font editor, if you're up to the somewhat dense documentation. FontLab has a utility called [TypeTool](http://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/typetool/), a little more expensive but has a good reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Is this definitely: [ITC Fat Face](https://www.paratype.com/fonts/pt/itc_fat_face/) from Paratype.com by [Herbert Lubalin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herb_Lubalin), one of the most important graphic designers from the 70's.

[image: ITC Fat Face]

[image: kulu]

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is very difficult to find a font that matches the "kulu" logo 100%, however...

[Floral font](http://www.fontsplace.com/floral-wide-normal-free-font-download.html) looks close to it:

[image]

Making it narrower and taller will result in even closer look.

Comment: ah thanks! this is very close. The "K" is definitely more ornamental in their version, but this is a great starting point