# Developing a Typeface

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, export, typefaces, font-design

I have some typefaces in Illustrator and would like to export them as a font. Is there a free program that people could recommend? Or a database of font designers I can contact?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a font with Adobe Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/how-to-make-a-font-with-adobe-illustrator)

Answer (score 2):

Birdfont is at least today still a freebie (=pay what you want). It allows paste from Illustrator.  Another freebie is Font Forge.

There are several free online font editors. They do not allow glyph imports.  The original design stays in the cloud. That can be a strategy for the already planned upcoming payments.

Comment: Just came across http://glyphrstudio.com/ - seems like an interesting project, though I haven't worked with it yet.