# Create Font using PNG files

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, png

I want to create my own Font using some images that formatted as `.PNG`.

is there any tool to create fonts using this method or anyway to do this ?
because i'm more comfortable to create characters in **Photoshop** and save them as `.PNG`

Thanks,

Comment: See [How to make a font with Adobe Illustrator?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/3253); creating a font involves much more than drawing shapes (and you at least need vector shapes, not a raster image).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What type of designs do you have, and in what context do you want to use your font?

Yes, you can totally use images to create a font that will retain the textures and colors of your images - if that's what you want. There is a new font format called OpenType-SVG that lets you do this (so the output will be actually be a bitmap font).

Photoshop CC 2017 supports OpenType-SVG fonts and you could leverage your PS skills to create fonts with Fontself, an add-on that runs within Photoshop (I am one of its creators ;)

Having said that, if you don't need the shades and just want to export a vector font that you can use in any other app, you could also trace your image letters into vector Shape Layers, and export them as a regular vector OpenType font, also using Fontself for Photoshop.

Have a look at the creative process here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tUM8MlMkeMI

Whatever the tool, have fun ;)

[image: Turn images into fonts in Photoshop with Fontself]

Comment: That's a modern approach with modern tools - quite different than the one  I suggested straight from the stone-age. Today hires bitmap fonts really are possible and the color is a high bonus.

Answer (score 3):

Stop and start proper vector drawing (Illustrator, Inkscape etc..)

The reasons:

- PNGs are bitmaps, but the fonts are generally vector shapes. The bitmap fonts still exist, but they have fixed sizes, an attempt to scale makes them messy.
- PNGs are convertible to vector drawings, but the accuracy is often poor. Actually the accuracy is 100%, but in bitmap there simply does not exists all the information on what you have thought. Thin lines and sharp corners suffer often badly and need some heavy manual fixing. If you can do that fixing, you as well can draw the shapes in the vector domain from the very beginning.

In Illustrator you can convert your existing bitmaps to vectors, fix them, and copy to a font editor. Illustrator is good for editing and combining already existing graphic material - for ex. you can reuse same shape relatively easy in different places in differant glyphs

You must have a proper font editor. Without it is extremely impractical to try to manage the font information which is much more than the glyphs.

ADDENDUM: To start easily, get Scanahand. It generates a font from handwriting.

http://www.high-logic.com/font-generator/scanahand.html

Nothing prevents you to put your bitmap glyphs onto the handwriting form in Photoshop (or equivalent) instead of scanning. It accepts 200 pix wide and 180 pix high glyphs (practically only half of this space is usable). Fill the form, feed it into Scanahand and your font is soon ready. Not the highest quality, but easy to use. It has 30 day trial.

Comment: I agree that for creating a personal font from scratch, one needs a proper font editor. All the vector-making tools are already included in those, so it might complicate the work-flow, using another tool too, like Illustrator - unless the user is already very experienced in a "classic" vector editor. Still, in the end, one has to jump off the cliff and learn at least the basics about the font editor, so why not try making the vectors where they need to go anyway.

I would only try bitmap -> vector conversion if I had super clear and crisp line-art drafts. Otherwise just trace by editor.

Comment: @alix54 a fast option is added

Comment: thank you for this lateral approach with scanahand. It might give alix54 a nice kickstart. - I purchased such a tool long ago and am upset that it does not work any more on modern windows (and in virtual machines it does not work with the scanners). This is off topic almost but I will try this, because at my last search, I had only found online tools. This looks good. A forum ist a great place when on top of help, or while trying to give help, you also received unrequested bonuses.

Answer (score 1):

It is good that you already have some shapes - even as bitmaps.

Please have a look at Fontforge. Commercial font editors are rather costly and your question sounds as if you want to try this out with one font for starters. (You might also be surprised how much work it is to get one font designed and to tune-up all the spacings and to figure out all the meta-information.)

In Fontforge you have layers and you can place your bitmaps (drafts or whatever they are) underneath your working surface to guide your vector-making.

In the Fontforge documentation they are ready for your idea: quote "Let us assume you already have a bitmap image of the glyph you are working on. Select the Import command from the File menu and import that image. It will be scaled so that it is as high as the em-square." Fontforge has got lots of documentation; can be somewhat overwhelming, depending on your learning style and previous experience, just see whether you like the tool and its eco-system. (I am not afiliated; I also use Typetool3, but not for making fonts, rather for hacking existing ones.)

http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/

Enjoy making your (first?) own font.