# Where can I create and publish a font?

Tags: fonts, typography, typefaces, font-design

I appreciate good and professional typefaces, but always think that I can improve or customize them for my needs. But where can I design and possibly publish my fonts online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit broad and difficult to give a specific answer, but to produce fonts you need [software](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3253) and then to publish fonts start by looking at the largest [publishers](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15926) first and read their documentation.

Independent font publishing is possible via [Behance](https://www.behance.net/search?search=free%20font) for instance where many freelancers are posting 'home-made' fonts, some of which are quite popular.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations and insights, I will take a look at these.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts aren't generally designed using online services. I suspect what you are really looking for is font creation software such as fontforge (free), or fontographer (not free).

It's unlikely you will be legally allowed to improve/alter commercial fonts, since these are generally copyright, and as such, making derivatives would breach copyright.

You can publish fonts using services such as dafont.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations and insights, I will visit them, I guess the subject is much braoder than I anticipated after all.

Comment: @SydneyKT Just so you don’t go into this completely blind, you should be aware that creating high-quality fonts like those used to set books, magazines, newspapers, etc., takes a long time. It includes many years of experience and knowledge of typography, kerning, and aesthetics, a very steep learning curve for the software and knowledge about how font tables interact and such things—not to mention actually designing each glyph. For professional type designers creating a single typeface is often a project which takes several years of work.